# How to expose multiple ports on one container in AWS behind ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation

The whole application consists of two servers (RabbitMQ and Tomcat) and a DB running behind ALB. For the time being there will be only one RabbitMQ instance and one Tomcat instance however the set up should allow to scale. Both servers run in their own Docker containers. I use ECS and CloudFormation to achieve this.

The problem is with the RabbitMQ server. This server must listen on two different ports - one for WebSocket connections (port 15674) and another one for HTTP connections for the Management API (port 15672). WebSocket connections are established from clients/browsers. HTTP connections happen internally from Tomcat to RabbitMQ however they also go through the ALB.
I can’t find a way to set up the RabbitMQ container so traffic goes to it on both ports. 
I am sharing the parts of the CloudFormation template which are relevant to the RabbitMQ server.
Using this template, the WebSocket connections seem to work fine but the HTTP connections fail with 404 error messages. 
Ideas how to enable the HTTP connections (port 15672) are appreciated.

```
  ECSAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup"
    Properties:
      VPCZoneIdentifier:        
        - Ref: "Subnet1"
        - Ref: "Subnet2"
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref "AutoScalingGroupConfig"
      MinSize: "1"
      MaxSize: "1"
      DesiredCapacity: "1"
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: "PT5M"
    UpdatePolicy:
      AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
        WillReplace: true
...
  ECSALB:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer"
    DependsOn: "AttachGateway"
    Properties:
      Name: "ECSALB"
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
        - Key: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds
          Value: 30
      Subnets: 
        - Ref: "Subnet1"
        - Ref: "Subnet2"
      SecurityGroups: [!Ref "LoadBalancerSecurityGroup"]
...
  ALBRabbitMQManagementListener:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener"
    DependsOn: [ "ECSServiceRole", "RabbitMQTargetGroup" ]
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: "forward"
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref "RabbitMQTargetGroup"
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref "ECSALB"
      Port: 15672
      Protocol: "HTTP"
...
  ALBListenerHTTPS:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener"
    DependsOn: [ "ECSServiceRole", "ECSALB" ]
    Properties:
      Certificates:
        - CertificateArn: “some_certificate”      
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: "redirect"
          RedirectConfig: 
            Protocol: "HTTPS"
            Host: "static.domain.com"
            Path: "/#{path}"
            Query: "#{query}"
            StatusCode: "HTTP_301"
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref "ECSALB"
      Port: 443
      Protocol: "HTTPS"
...
  ECSALBListenerRuleWebSocket:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::ListenerRule"
    DependsOn: [ "ALBListenerHTTPS", "RabbitMQTargetGroup" ]
    Properties:
      Actions:
        - Type: "forward"
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref "RabbitMQTargetGroup"
      Conditions:
        - Field: "path-pattern"
          Values: [ "/ws" ]
      ListenerArn: !Ref "ALBListenerHTTPS"
      Priority: 2
...
  RabbitMQTargetGroup:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup"
    DependsOn: "ECSALB"
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 30
      HealthCheckPath: "/"
      HealthCheckPort: 15672
      HealthCheckProtocol: "HTTP"
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 5
      HealthyThresholdCount: 2
      Name: "RabbitMQTargetGroup"
      Port: 15674 
      Protocol: "HTTP"
      TargetGroupAttributes:
        - Key: "stickiness.enabled"
          Value: true  # Needed to support WebSockets
        - Key: "stickiness.lb_cookie.duration_seconds"
          Value: 604800  # One week (this is the maximum)
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 3
      VpcId: !Ref "Vpc"
...
  RabbitMQService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: [ "ALBListenerHTTPS", "RabbitMQTargetGroup", "ECSALBListenerRuleWebSocket" ]
    Properties:
      Cluster: !Ref “MyCluster"
      Role: !Ref "ECSServiceRole"
      DesiredCount: 1
      TaskDefinition: !Ref "RabbitMQTask"
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: "rabbitmq-service"
          ContainerPort: 15674
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref "RabbitMQTargetGroup"
...
  RabbitMQTask:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
    Properties:
      Family: "rabbitmq-service"
      NetworkMode: "host"
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: "rabbitmq-service"
          Essential: true
          Image: “some_docker_image”
          MemoryReservation: 1024
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 15672
            - ContainerPort: 15674
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: "awslogs"
            Options:
              awslogs-group: "rabbitmq"
              awslogs-region: !Ref "AWS::Region"
              awslogs-stream-prefix: “my_prefix”
              awslogs-datetime-format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L"
```

Comment: Seems like I am asking the wrong question. After some debugging I realized both connections work. The 404 responses come from the Cowboy server i.e. the management API (on port 15672) gets hit. Somehow the request that reaches RabbitMQ is not the right one. The request looks like this: `http://ECSALB-<ALB-ID-HERE>.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com:15672/api/exchanges/%2f/my_exchange_name_here` Probably escaping "/" in the url gets broken somehow when it goes through the ALB. Once I pinpoint the exact reason I will reply here.